# TailwindCSS Autoprefixer not working | flex

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, autoprefixer

Hi I used tailwind in my react project but when I build the project, the autoprefixer doesn't work properly

**tailwind.config.js:**

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}"],
  theme: {
    container: {
      center: true,
      padding: "1rem",
    },
    extend: {},
    },
  },
  plugins: [
     require('autoprefixer')
  ]
};
```

I wanna autoprefixer work for every flex property like:

```css
.flex{
    display: flex;
}
```

to

```css
.flex{
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
}
```

browserslist package.json:

```json
{
  ....

  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },

  ...
}
```

**I want all flex properties to work in all browsers, because, for example, on an old phone in the Safari browser, the *gap* property does not work correctly.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need install **PostCSS** and setup like here:

> Installing Tailwind CSS as a PostCSS plugin is the most seamless way to integrate it with build tools like webpack, Rollup, Vite, and Parcel. [Tailwind documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/using-postcss)

And second step, reduce the percentage of support from **>0.2%** to **>0.01%** in both enviroments.

##### browserslist package.json:

```json
{
  ....

  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.01%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      ">0.01%",
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },

  ...
}
```

[image]

Finnaly, you can remove the autoprefixer plugin from **tailwind.config.js** .

Answer (score 0):

In the `index.css` file or where you imprort tailwind,

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

You can extend components and utilities using

```
@layer utilities {
    .flex {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably missing a custom extension like `.svelte` in the `tailwind.config.js`.
Since it ignored .svelte files, it did not see the `flex` class and did not include it in the `output.css` file.

The following change fixed it for me:
[image]